# Update Linux's terminal screen in loop

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

I wrote the following simple code in windows and dots print normally in CMD in each step of loop :

```
 for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
 {
  cout<<i;
  Sleep(1000);
 }
```

but this code in Linux do not print dots in each step of the loop , it wait for 5 seconds, after it print all the dots :

```
 for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
 {
  cout<<i;
  pause(1);
 }
```

How can it update the terminal output screen in each loop step ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ensure that the output is actually flushed onto the screen, you need to call flush:

```
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
 {
  cout<<i;
  cout.flush();
  pause(1);
 }
```

Comment: Correct, and this also works: `cout<<i<<flush;`. It can be more convenient as it's a one-liner.